# Why is ephedrine optically active?

Tags: stereochemistry, chirality

Acyclic amine in which three groups are different with a lone pair of electron is optically inactive and nitrogen is achiral because of the rapid pyramidal inversion.

[image]
Does similar inversion happen in ephedrine?
If yes, doesn't the inversion cancel the optical activity of the chiral carbon. So why then is ephedrine optically active?

[image]

Comment: Nitrogen is not the only chiral center here.

Comment: @Ivan Doesn't the inversion cancel the optical activity of the chiral carbon?

Comment: No, why? Inversion happens on nitrogen, not on carbon.

Comment: @Ivan One group attached to the nitrogen is bit bulky so does the inversion happen and is the nitrogen chiral?

Comment: I don't think inversion takes place here. But in any case, why inversion should affect or remove the chirality of near C?

Comment: @Alchimista Is the nitrogen chiral?

Comment: There are two chiral carbon centres in ephedrine, neither are affected by nitrogen inversion

Comment: @AsherAbraham I am not sure but you can easily search for this specific question. Perhaps no as for inversion is at work. But again there are two other stereo centers...

Comment: Why are you trying to cancel on optical rotation from things that are not completely identical?!

Comment: @Alchimista Nitrogen inversion most certainly happens here as there is nothing fixing the nitrogen atom into one defined configuration (including not in a planar structure). That’s obviously irrelevant for the question of the molecule’s overall chirality.

Comment: @Jan I know is irrelevant. I was just not sure about inversion, thinking of the bulkiness of one substituent. Nice to know.

Comment: @Alchimista I mean, nitrogen inversion is best thought of as the nitrogen swinging through the plane of the other atoms. They have minimal configurational changes, nitrogen moves far more ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nitrogen will always perform nitrogen inversion if it is not configurationally fixed due to steric or electronic reasons. Fixing the configuration sterically could be achieved, for example, by a polycyclic compound as in **1** below. Fixing the configuration electronically is exemplified by the amide **2** (note that the amide is achiral; the nitrogen is forced into a planar configuration by amide resonance as shown).

[image: a chiral 1-azabicyclo[3.2.1]octane (compound 1) and *N*-ethyl-*N*-methylacetamide (compound 2) with the amide resonance shown]
**Figure 1:** examples of nitrogen-containing compounds where nitrogen inversion is not possible. **1** is chiral, **2** is not.

However, nitrogen inversion only concerns *nitrogen* atoms and prevents most nitrogens in organic compounds from being asymmetric even if they are attached to three different residues (including a lone pair). Ephedrine contains two additional asymmetric atoms both of which are carbon atoms. These carbons *cannot* perform an inversion similar to nitrogen inversion as they are covalently bound to four different residues. As there is no plane or centre of symmetry transforming one of these asymmetric carbon atoms onto the other, this makes the molecule as a whole chiral.

The effect of the asymmetric carbon atoms can be seen in the number of possible stereoisomers: both carbons can be either (*R*) or (*S*) configured giving 4 possible isomers ((+)-ephedrine, (–)-ephedrine, (+)-pseudoephedrine and (–)-pseudoephedrine). If nitrogen inversion were not a thing, we would expect 8 stereoisomers as then each of these 4 could occur with an (*S*) or an (*R*) configured nitrogen. However, only those four are known.

For an abundance of clarity: nitrogen inversion *only* affects nitrogen atoms and *only* turns an (*R*)-nitrogen centre into an (*S*)-nitrogen centre; non-nitrogen centres are unaffected.